# Regex remove whole block whoch contain this words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

```
myzol+\s+(.*)-[0-9]+\s\{[\mrzulf\](.*?)\}
```

```
The lines
here is me
you are there
my fav

gvt
hjk hlkjhf c

myzol 123gbhj {
    test
    check      myself/mrzulf/.com
}

myzol 123gbhj {
    test
    check      myself/mrzulf/.com
}

myzol 1fde3gbhj {
    test
    check      myself/check/.com
}

myzol 12ecehj {
    test
    check      myself/mrzulf/.com
}

myzol 1evehj {
    test
    check      myself/check/.com
}
```

Here I have to remove the block which contains mrzulf
I have to replace it with blank.

Comment: You can use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php instead of regex

Comment: Then how will I match that block

Comment: Try `myzol+\s+.*{[^{}]*\bmrzulf\b[^{}]*}` https://regex101.com/r/B4LowA/1

Comment: Thank The fourth bird it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `-` in the example strings, and not all the examples end on a digit before the curly like in this part of the pattern `[0-9]+\s\{`

You can match:

```
\bmyzol\s+[^{]*{[^{}]*\bmrzulf\b[^{}]*}
```

And replace with an empty string.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Zp5hM/1)

If there should be a space and word characters before the opening `{` then, and if you do not want to match newlines before the opening `{`:

```
\bmyzol\h+\w+\h+{[^{}]*\bmrzulf\b[^{}]*}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ko8pNa/1)

Comment: @mickmackusa The sin of copying and pasting :-)

Comment: What PCRE10.35 violation am I encountering with `\R` in https://3v4l.org/gN3Lm ?  I don't see/know it.

Comment: @mickmackusa I don't know what you mean by that, it works here https://regex101.com/r/Mv0Uvw/1 and it works in your php demo. Do you get en error somewhere?

Comment: Notice how it removes all 3 qualifying sections in PHP7.4.0 - PHP7.4.11, but every version above that (PHP7.4.12 and hogher) misses a section.  It is to do with `\R`, but I don't know why.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry for the late response, I looked at it and could not find any explanation 2 days ago. Tonight I was searching because I was still curious. On [this page](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php) about php version 7.4.12 it states Updated to PCRE [10.35](http://www.rexegg.com/pcre-doc/10.35/). There is also a line that states: Fixed bug [#80118](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80118) (Erroneous whitespace match with JIT only). So my guess is that it is related to that, but I can not tell for sure. If you change the `.+` in the pattern to `.*` it works, also if you use `\R{2}`.

Comment: I was told in the PHP chat room to post a bug report in PCRE2. https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/issues/133